# get count with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, filter, count, type-conversion, dynamic-arrays

I've transformed the dataset with power query and loaded it into Excel. In one column values are both text and numbers. In power query, this shows as text & number. When I transform it into excel data is only stored as text. I want to get the count from that column based on multiple criteria. I used COUNTIFS function to do that as below.

> =COUNTIFS(Yearly_Data[Medical Year],Processing!$B$32,Yearly_Data[Attribute],Processing!$A$34,Yearly_Data[Value],"<"&70,Yearly_Data[Value],">"&100)

Due to data stored as text, it returns 0, but there must be a value greater than 0. Also, I tested the dynamic array which is converted to numeric values, within the COUNTIFS function as below.

> =COUNTIFS(VALUE(FILTER(Yearly_Data[Value],Yearly_Data[Attribute]=Processing!$A$34,"")),">100")

It returns an error. I am using Office 365 latest. I am trying to get the number of values greater than 100. Can anybody give an idea to achieve this task?

[image]

this function is to get the number of values>100 for blood sugar.

[image]

my values related to tests can be discovered from the above image of the table. in the values column data is stored as the text & I can not convert it within the table due to both text and numbers contained within that column.

Answer (score 0):

Countifs works that all the criterias must be met. In your formula you want to get less then 70 **and** greater then 100 which always returns 0.

Therefore try to use to sum the 2 criterias something like this:

```
=COUNTIFS(Yearly_Data[Medical Year],Processing!$B$32,Yearly_Data[Attribute],Processing!$A$34,Yearly_Data[Value],"<"&70)+COUNTIFS(Yearly_Data[Medical Year],Processing!$B$32,Yearly_Data[Attribute],Processing!$A$34,Yearly_Data[Value],">"&100)
```

If texts are in the value cells then try this formula

```
=SUM((Yearly_data[Medical Year]=Processing!$B$32)*(Yearly_data[Attribute]=Processing!$A$34)*(IF(VALUE(Yearly_data[Value])<70,1,0)+IF(VALUE(Yearly_data[Value])>100,1,0)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But there is a problem with this. This is also returning the 0 counts.  The main reason I think that values are stored as text in a column. COUNTIFS does not consider the text values in this function. We need to transform the text into values while calculating.

Comment: Added another formula for text input in Value column